# source R file from private gitlab with basic auth

Tags: r, gitlab

I would like to source an .R file from a private gitlab serveur. I need to use the basic authentication with user/password

I tried this kind of instruction without succes

```
httr::GET("http://vpsxxxx.ovh.net/root/project/raw/9f8a404b5b33c216d366d80b7d48e34577598069/R/script.R", 
authenticate("user", "password",type="basic"))
```

any idea?

Regards

edit : I found this way... but I need to download all the project...

```
bundle <- tempfile()
git2r::clone("http://vpsxxx.ovh.net/root/projet.git",
             bundle, credentials=git2r::cred_user_pass("user", "password"))
source(file.path(bundle,"R","script.R"))
```

Comment: I am interested in the solution! Have the same issue right now. I know how to install package hosted on gitlab with `install_git` but not source a file. Will come up with something but if it already exist it would help.

Comment: I manage to get the file using the gitlab API and `gitlabr`.

Comment: can you please share your code ?

Comment: Posted my code. Tell me if it work for you or not.

Comment: Any news? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use gitlab API to get a file from a repository. `gitlabr` can help you do that. Current version 0.9 is compatible with apiV3 and V4.

This should work (it work on my end on a private gitlab with apiv3)

```r
library(gitlabr)
my_gitlab <- gl_connection("https://private-gitlab.com",
                       login = "username",
                       password = "password",
                       api_version = "v4") # by default. put v3 here if needed
my_file <- my_gitlab(gl_get_file, project = "project_name", file_path = "path/to/file")
```

This will get you a character version of your file. You can also get back a raw version to deal with it in another way.

```
raw <- gl_get_file(project = "project_name",
                   file_path = "file/to/path",
                   gitlab_con = my_gitlab,
                   to_char = F)
temp_file <- tempfile()
writeBin(raw, temp_file)
```

You can now source the code

```
source(temp_file)
```

It is one solution among others. I did not manage to source the file without using the API.

Know that : 
* You can use an Access Token instead of username and password
* You can use the `gitlabr` several ways. It is documented in the vignette. I used 2 differents ways here.
* Version 1.0 will not be compatible with v3 api. But I think you use v4.

Feel free to get back to me so that I update this post if need a clearer answer.